# Draw graphics without deleting them when using repaint()

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have a draw method and I want the drawLine to remain on the screen after I call repaint(). The fillOval will be moving, that is ok. But i want the drawLine to be redraw just on another position without deleting it.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(x, y, x+10, y+10);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the original drawline still to be there in addition to it's new position? or you simply want the same line in the redrawn in it's new position after the repaint occurs?

Comment: Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method NOT the paint() method. How do people keep finding examples using the paint() method?

Comment: @camickr simple answer ---> on all Java Swing Examples Depots, and without any exception e.g. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm tec...

Comment: That site should be banned for painting problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `x` and `y` of every line in a `List`. On each `repaint()`, you just redraw all the lines present in the `List`

Comment: This approach seems redundant. Why not just limit the area you repaint, instead of repainting everything and doing unnecessary bookkeeping?

Comment: @mre it really depends on what he want to do. It is not redundant in case of the next repaint, he want to translate the lines by let's say 10 pixels, etc.

Comment: @mre Although you could limit the area you repaint in theory, this way will be more robust. If the window is partially obscured because the another window that overlaps is selected, or minimizes the window, the entire application screen may need to be re-drawn. And then what? You have to do a full repaint. And then you're going to need all that book-keeping to re-create what was already on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

In the repaint request, you must specify the coordinates and dimensions of the "dirty area" by using one of the following methods:

- [`repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
- [`repaint(Rectangle r)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)

Note that you'll want to override `paintComponent`, not `paint` when performing custom painting.

Comment: nice answer, even I still think that about super & dispose +1